# Join three tables and specifically sort columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have three dataframes that differ only by one column. They list a mean, std dev and count as shown below:

table 1

```
Name Treatment Pool_mean
ATP  1Week     100
ATP  4Week    500
ATP  16Weeks   1500
GTP  4Week     1000
GTP  1Week     250
GTP  16Weeks   12000
```

table 2

```
Name Treatment Pool_std
ATP  1Week     2
ATP  4Week    5
ATP  16Weeks   15
GTP  4Week     7
GTP  1Week     2
GTP  16Weeks   30
```

table 3

```
Name Treatment Pool_count
ATP  1Week     3
ATP  4Week    5
ATP  16Weeks   4
GTP  4Week     5
GTP  1Week     3
GTP  16Weeks   4
```

I need to get a table that looks like this:

```
           1Week     1Week   1Week        4Weeks    4Weeks    4Weeks    16Weeks 16Weeks 16 Weeks
           pool_mean pool_std pool_count pool_mean pool_std pool_count pool_mean pool_std pool_count
  Name ATP 100        2        3         500        5         5         1500       15          4      
  Name GTP 250        2        3         1000       7         5         12000      30          4
```

I just don't know what to do. I got as far as writing this code:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(averages)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(stddev)
df3 = pd.DataFrame(count)
dfs = [df1, df2, df3]
dfs1 = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1).T.drop_duplicates().T
print(dfs1)
dfs1.to_csv('pool_merged.csv')
```

But it just ends up putting my columns into one pretty flat file, which is great but not what I need. I am really lost at this point (I am very new to this).

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: in the dataframes you have 4Week  and 4Weeks with an extra s , is that expected?

Comment: No, it's just my misspelling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below solution which concats with set index and unstack , then swaplevel and sort index using natsort:

```
import natsort as ns
dfs = [df1,df2,df3]
out = (pd.concat([i.set_index(['Name','Treatment']).unstack() for i in dfs],axis=1)
      .swaplevel(axis=1))
out = out.reindex(columns=ns.natsorted(out.columns.get_level_values(0).unique()),level=0)
```

---

```
print(out)

Treatment     1Week                         4Week                      \
          Pool_mean Pool_std Pool_count Pool_mean Pool_std Pool_count   
Name                                                                    
ATP             100        2          3       500        5          5   
GTP             250        2          3      1000        7          5   

Treatment   16Weeks                      
          Pool_mean Pool_std Pool_count  
Name                                     
ATP            1500       15          4  
GTP           12000       30          4
```